# eiffel c compilation failure: error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors, eiffel, eiffel-studio-18

I'm trying to get familiar with Eiffel language so I've installed Eiffel Studio 18 and created a Graphics application. Compilation failed with message:

```
Preparing C compilation using already configured msc C compiler...
ERROR: Cannot start "nmake".ERROR: Cannot start "nmake".
```

Documentation suggested that `espawn` utility may show available toolchains, however it seems to crash:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.07 GPL\tools\spec\win64\bin> & "C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.07 GPL\tools\spec\win64\bin\espawn.exe" -l
Eiffel Environment Command Spawn Utility - Version: 18.07
Copyright Eiffel Software 1985-2018. All Rights Reserved.

Available C/C++ compilers:


espawn: system execution failed.
Following is the set of recorded exceptions:

******************************** Thread exception *****************************
In thread           Root thread            0x0 (thread id)
*******************************************************************************
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class / Object      Routine                Nature of exception           Effect
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APPLICATION         root's creation        Segmentation violation:
<000000000363C588>                         Operating system signal.      Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APPLICATION         root's creation
<000000000363C588>                         Routine failure.              Exit
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find any toolchain related stuff except for that espawn util so I've tried to launch Eiffel Studio from VS development command prompt hoping that it may implicitly rely on some environment variables. This indeed helped, however compilation still fails with linker error:

```
Preparing C compilation using already configured msc C compiler...
big_file_C28_c.c
eoption.c
big_file_E2_c.c
big_file_C26_c.c
big_file_C27_c.c
big_file_C30_c.c
big_file_C29_c.c
big_file_C31_c.c
eref.c
epoly.c
esize.c
big_file_C25_c.c
big_file_C24_c.c
big_file_C23_c.c
big_file_C22_c.c
big_file_C21_c.c
big_file_C20_c.c
big_file_C19_c.c
eplug.c
eskelet.c
enames.c
evisib.c
big_file_C18_c.c
big_file_C17_c.c
big_file_C16_c.c
big_file_C15_c.c
big_file_C13_c.c
big_file_C14_c.c
ececil.c
big_file_C12_c.c
einit.c
eparents.c
big_file_C11_c.c
big_file_C10_c.c
big_file_C9_c.c
big_file_C8_c.c
big_file_C7_c.c
big_file_C6_c.c
big_file_C5_c.c
big_file_C4_c.c
big_file_C3_c.c
big_file_C2_c.c
big_file_C1_c.c
Скопировано файлов:         1.
emain.c
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 10.0.10011.16384
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27024.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

-STACK:5000000 -NODEFAULTLIB:libc -STACK:5000000 -NODEFAULTLIB:libc -SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS -OUT:my_wel_application_1.exe 
e1\emain.obj 
"C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.07 GPL\studio\spec\win64\lib\msc\finalized.lib" "C:\Program Files\Eiffel Software\EiffelStudio 18.07 GPL\library\wel\spec\msc\win64\lib\wel.lib" 
USER32.lib WS2_32.lib ADVAPI32.lib GDI32.lib SHELL32.lib MSIMG32.lib COMDLG32.lib UUID.lib OLE32.lib OLEAUT32.lib COMCTL32.lib MPR.LIB SHLWAPI.LIB WINSPOOL.LIB 
my_wel_application_1.res 
E2\Eobj2.lib E1\eparents.obj E1\einit.obj E1\ececil.obj E1\evisib.obj 
E1\enames.obj E1\eskelet.obj E1\eplug.obj E1\esize.obj E1\epoly.obj 
E1\eref.obj E1\eoption.obj C31\Cobj31.lib C30\Cobj30.lib C29\Cobj29.lib 
C28\Cobj28.lib C27\Cobj27.lib C26\Cobj26.lib C25\Cobj25.lib C24\Cobj24.lib 
C23\Cobj23.lib C22\Cobj22.lib C21\Cobj21.lib C20\Cobj20.lib C19\Cobj19.lib 
C18\Cobj18.lib C17\Cobj17.lib C16\Cobj16.lib C15\Cobj15.lib C14\Cobj14.lib 
C13\Cobj13.lib C12\Cobj12.lib C11\Cobj11.lib C10\Cobj10.lib C9\Cobj9.lib 
C8\Cobj8.lib C7\Cobj7.lib C6\Cobj6.lib C5\Cobj5.lib C4\Cobj4.lib 
C3\Cobj3.lib C2\Cobj2.lib C1\Cobj1.lib 
finalized.lib(econsole.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(console.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(except.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(sig.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(option.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob_func
finalized.lib(main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _set_output_format referenced in function eif_rtinit
finalized.lib(run_idr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
finalized.lib(except.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
finalized.lib(out.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
finalized.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
finalized.lib(store.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sprintf
finalized.lib(econsole.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vfprintf referenced in function print_err_msg
finalized.lib(file.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol fscanf referenced in function rt_swallow_nl
finalized.lib(retrieve.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sscanf referenced in function iread_header_new
finalized.lib(run_idr.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol sscanf
my_wel_application_1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
Stop.
```

Comment: This is apparently not about the C language.

Comment: It looks like you are missing one of the Microsoft runtimes and perhaps another lib. The open question is, why? I think you need to figure out how to get a verbose output from the Eiffel tool so it can be diagnosed further. In particular, how is the Eiffel tool invoking `link.exe`.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite This is about C language. About setting up C toolchain for eiffel environment in particular. Prelease restrain from removing C tag.

Comment: Just because there are C files involved does not mean it's about the C **language** as indicated by the tag. You might want to read the standard to see what the C language constitutes. Please refrain from adding unrelated tags to questions. That#s basically a software installation question.

Comment: @jww linker parameters are listed in compilation output, `-NODEFAULTLIB:libc` suggests that binary is not supposed to be linked to normal c runtime and some other libraries that look like runtime (`\lib\msc\finalized.lib` and `win64\lib\wel.lib`) are linked instead. However it is strange that `-NODEFAULTLIB:libc` is listed twice while unresolved symbols are clearly from c standard library.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite "linker error when compiling C code" - "not about the C language" - " basically a software installation question" - what kind of logic is this?

Comment: Seeing Linux libs in `-NODEFAULTLIB:libc` looks unusual to me. But I'm not familiar with Eiffel, the functionality it provides or its build process, so I should probably retire from the question.

Comment: Since when does a [**linker**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) **compile** a language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation error when running from VS development command prompt is related to the mismatch between C compiler version and used Eiffel run-time library. Setting the corresponding environment variable before launching the compilation should fix the issue:

```
    set ISE_C_COMPILER=msc_vc140
```

As to the original error, for some reason, C compilation fails on some machines, because EiffelStudio cannot find VS. The issue has even become a [FAQ](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/version/trunk/faq/FAQ).

Comment: This helped indeed. Though i had to start a new project. Also i must mention that FAQ page you've linked contains unreleased documentation while help links at eiffel website and IDE lead to different page without this suggestion and that there is a proper [documentation on required environment variables](https://dev.eiffel.com/Environment_Variables).